# Many-to-many insert using LINQ to SQL and ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, many-to-many

I have two Tables: `Products(ProductID, ProductName)` and  `Categories(CategoryID, CategoryName)` 
with a many-to-many relationship between `Products` and `Categories` `ProductsCategories(ProductID, CategoryID)`

How Can I Implement a view that enables a user to Add and Edit one product with many categories **using Asp.Net Mvc and LINQ to SQL**?

Answer (score 0):

Since LINQ to SQL only supports a strict 1:1 mapping with your database you would have to make a link table.  This would look something like...

[ProductCategories]
ID
ProductID (FK)
CategoryID (FK)

Then for every relationship of product to categories you would just make a new ProductCategories entity and insert it.  So given the data...

Products
ID Name
1 Apple
2 XBOX 360

Categories
ID Name
1 Produce
2 Electronics
3 Game Systems

Your link table would look like

ProductCategories
ID ProductID CategoryID
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 2 3

Comment: Thanks for help but My Question IS
How Can I Implement a view that enable user to add and Edit one prodcut to many category Using ASP.NET Mvc and LINQ TO SQL